# Binder invocation to an incorrect interface During ITelephony Implemetation

Tags: java, android

I have created ITelephony AIDL file as Interface as shown in picture attached. I am getting below error when using this code.

```
   Class<?> loadClass = CallBlockerPhoneStateListner.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("android.os.ServiceManager");
                Method method = loadClass.getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
                IBinder invoke = (IBinder) method.invoke(null, TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                ITelephony iTelephony = ITelephony.Stub.asInterface(invoke);
                iTelephony.endCall();
```

Error thrown:

```
06-21 11:31:26.977 17511-17511/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
06-21 11:31:26.977 17511-17511/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
06-21 11:31:26.977 17511-17511/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
06-21 11:31:26.977 17511-17511/? W/System.err:     at jss.s.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.endCall(ITelephony.java:131)
```

Can u guide how to fix this? Ref was taken from `https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=384401056/itheima/itheima-master/MobileSafe/src/com/blueice/mobilesafe/service/BlackListService.java#`

[image: AIDL Image]

Answer (score 0):

packagename should be com.android.internal.telephony instead of your app package name in aidl directory.